# libgdx and drwaing app

Tags: drawing, libgdx

I am looking at using LibGdx to write a simple drawing app. The user gestures would be used for drawing rectangles and other shapes. Is it a good idea to use Libgdx for such an app? If yes could someone point to an example which shows how to draw shapes using libgdx and gestures.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the LibGDX tests that does drawing.  All of the source code for LibGDX including the tests can be found here:

http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx

As for the shapes, there is a shape renderer, I have never used it, but you could maybe use it for a drawing game.  Best of luck.